# How to create native events from strings using event constructors?

Tags: javascript, dom, events, dom-events

The `document.createEvent` [API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent) is being deprecated. It allowed for native browser event creation using using the string names of those events. The now recommended way is to use [event constructors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) instead.

i.e. `createEvent("HtmlEvents")` has now become `new HtmlEvent()`.

Is it possible to create these events with an event constructor using strings? i.e. `new CustomEvent("HtmlEvents")`?

Comment: The [documentation of the `CustomEvent` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent) has an example...

Comment: @HereticMonkey the question is, if I create a `new CustomEvent("HtmlEvents")`, will it behave the same as an event created using `document.createEvent("HtmlEvents")`.

Comment: No, because there is no such built-in event type `HtmlEvents`. I mean, it's easy to check, right? Just run `document.createEvent("HtmlEvents")` in the console and compare the output with `new CustomEvent("HtmlEvents")`...

Comment: @HereticMonkey That's the problem. I need to create these events using strings as a migration for old code. I could of course just make a giant switch statement with a case for each event, but I would like to avoid that.

Comment: @HereticMonkey A little, but the old event types usually have pluralized names. I have tried searching for a list of all the names, but have not found any yet.  
It's either this, or migrating ~1500 tests.

Comment: Just remove the `s`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even the event constructors are just keys on the global `window` object:

```js
function createEvent(type, ...eventArgs) {
  return new window[type](eventArgs);
}

// examples:
console.log(
  createEvent("KeyboardEvent", "keyboard event name"),
  createEvent("MouseEvent", "mouse event name"),
);
```

Comment: Interesting... How come the `createEvent` names are pluralized while the constructors are not? *Edit: * Looks like it's both https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent#Notes

Comment: This is exactly what the answers to the proposed duplicate say.

Comment: @HereticMonkey thanks for pointing that out, I didn't see that while writing my answer. I voted to close in favor of the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you

```
var event = new Event('build');

// Listen for the event.
elem.addEventListener('build', function (e) { /* ... */ }, false);

// Dispatch the event.
elem.dispatchEvent(event);
```

for creating custom event

```
var event = new CustomEvent('build', { detail: elem.dataset.time });
function eventHandler(e) {
  console.log('The time is: ' + e.detail);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not. I need to know how to create the native event types, i.e. `new MouseEvent` or `new HtmlEvent` using string names. I need to migrate old code which makes use of these names.